# Getting unexpected data from InputStream

Tags: android

I have some strange device from my friend which doesn't have UUID but I want to read data from it via Bluetooth. So I create something like this

```
class ReadData extends Thread {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    ByteArrayInputStream arrayData;
    OutputStream outputData;
    InputStream inputData;
    InputStreamReader inputDataReader;
    int bytes;
    MessageDigest md = null;

    ReadData(BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket) throws IOException {
        outputData = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
        inputData = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //byte [] bytesToSend = {0x0F, 'T', 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0x02, 0x05, 0x10, 0x06, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, md.digest()[0], md.digest()[1], 0x0D };
        //byte [] bytesToSend = {0x0F, 'R', md.digest()[0], md.digest()[1], 0x0D };
        //byte [] bytesToSend = {0x0F, 'S', md.digest()[0], md.digest()[1], 0x0D };
        byte [] bytesToSend = {0x0F, 'A', md.digest()[0], md.digest()[1], 0x0D };
        Log.i("BYTES TO SEND", "" + bytesToSend);
        outputData.write(bytesToSend);
        Log.i("DATA_TO_SEND", outputData.toString());
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try {
                bytes = inputData.read(buffer, 0, inputData.available());
                inputDataReader = new InputStreamReader(inputData);
                Log.i("RETRIVED_DATA", "" + inputDataReader.read());

                outputData.close();
                inputData.close();
            } catch( IOException e){

            } catch ( IllegalStateException e){
                Log.e("ERROR_APEARED", "" + bytes);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I get bluetooth socket and how I pass it to constructor of ReadData:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
BluetoothSocket clientSocket =  null;
BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(devices.get(i).getAddress());
                Method m = remoteDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});
                clientSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(remoteDevice, 1);
```

But when I 'Log.i' data which I am receiving from the device and I got for some reason number 15, why? What am I doing wrong?

ps. bytesToSend arrays those are the command which I need to send to a device for querying it. But I am not sure is it correct, I get documentation which says:

```
commands:
  'R' - request for current RTC status
  <0x0F><'R'><CKSH><CKSL><0x0D>
```

Is it correct? To send queries like I am doing? Or I misunderstand documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
bytes = inputData.read(buffer, 0, inputData.available());
inputDataReader = new InputStreamReader(inputData);
Log.i("RETRIVED_DATA", "" + inputDataReader.read());
```

Five errors in three lines:

1. You are misusing `available()` and thereby presenting a possible read count of zero, or more than the buffer length.
2. You are ignoring the byte count, which can be zero with this code, or -1 indicating end of stream.
3. If the byte count was zero you are in a spin-loop instead of a blocking read.
4. You are then ignoring the data just read altogether.
5. You are then logging the next byte(s).

It should be:

```
bytes = inputData.read(buffer);
// Note that bytes cannot now be zero, as buffer.length > 0
if (bytes == -1)
   break;
Log.i("RETRIEVED_DATA", new String(buffer, 0, bytes));
```

NB This:

```
Log.i("DATA_TO_SEND", outputData.toString());
```

is futile. I/O streams don't yields anything interesting when converted to strings. It should be:

```
 Log.i("DATA_TO_SEND", Arrays.toString(bytesToSend));
```

Comment: your String constructor is odd

Comment: My IDE complain about new String(inputData, 0, bytes) can not resolve constructor String(InputStream, int, int).

Comment: That Help me. Thank you. But know I am getting error for some reason.  Could someone please explain me how I suppose to translate the command, above, translate into java code? I can add the CKSH and CKSL are the checksum and I am thinking that is the problem I am not sure how to pass it into my code.

Comment: Impossible to say without further information, or knowing what the device is, but CKSL and CKSH won't be bytes of a message digest, they will be bytes of a checksum or CRC-16 of some kind, which will be specified in the documentation for the device. Not that you're not constructing the message digest correctly in the first place.